# Is there way to add text view and button inside the table row on the same time (Using Android Java)

Tags: android

I currently have problem on my module part of the project which I don't think if this possible to have text view and button inside the table row on the same time.

Problem: How to put button and text view inside the table row?

I will share to you guys my sample output that I already created on my project.

[image: my output]

as you can see there is two table row already created, so right now I want to have button on each table row. what I mean for this, on the bottom part of the number I want to insert button.

**Here is my Sample Code:**

```
    <TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


    <TextView
            
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/red_500"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@color/transparent"
            android:text="78,130.47"


            />


    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/blue_500"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@color/transparent"
            android:text="78,130.47" />


</TableRow>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where exactly do You want to add a button? On the 1st or 2nd option? [check here](https://imgur.com/EOFT5BM). Or if I understand wrong You can edit answer and add what You want

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the TextView & Button in a LinearLayout in vertical orientation.

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/red_500"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@color/transparent"
            android:text="78,130.47"
            />

     <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Click me" />
            
     </LinearLayout>

<!--  Similarly for second view -->

</TableRow>
```